# importing a function which involves another function python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I came across a strange situation while writing two separate functions in same ".py" file. I am using python 2.7.12. Here is my code:

```
def do_the_job(n, list):
    for i in range(2, n):
        a = list[i - 1]
        b = list[i - 2]
        ap_me = list[i- a] + list[i - b]
        list.append(ap_me)
    return list

def func_two(n, k):
    counter = 0
    list = [1, 1]
    do_the_job(n,list)
    for i in range(n):
        if list[i] >= k:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

Then for import, I write `from my_py import func_two` to console. When I write `func_two(10,3)` it imports `do_the_job` function too and runs successfully. However, here comes the reason of the post, when I write `do_the_job(7,[1,1])` to console, it errors as `NameError: name 'do_the_job' is not defined`.

How come I can use `do_the_job` function as a part of `func_two` function with importing `func_two`, but cannot use it on its own with same import status?

Comment: `func_two` is run in it's own namespace in that module it exists in, where `do_the_job` is just above it and does not have to be imported.

Comment: On a different note, it's a bad idea to call your list, 'list', as you've then replaced the built-in `list()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Functions are given a reference to a *global namespace*. That namespace is the module they are defined in.

Because both `func_two` and `do_the_job` are defined in the same module, they both 'live' in that namespace. Using the name `do_the_job` in the  body of `func_two` will be resolved by looking at the globals for `func_two` and that'll find the other function.

When you import a module, the *whole* module is always loaded; you can find it in the `sys.modules` mapping. Once loaded (which only needs to be done once), the importing namespace is updated to add the names you imported; these are just references to objects in the imported module namespace.

So the `from my_py import func_two` import ensures the `my_py` module is loaded (stored in `sys.modules['my_py']`) and then the name `func_two` is added to your *current* namespace to reference `sys.modules['my_py'].func_two`.

You did not, however, import `do_the_job` into your current namespace, so you can't use that name. It is not part of your global namespace. Either import it explicitly, or reference it via `sys.modules['my_py'].do_the_job`.

You may want to read up on how Python names work, I can heartily recommend you read [Ned Batchelder's *Facts and myths about Python names and values*](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). It doesn't directly cover importing, but it does offer vital insights that'll help you understand this specific situation better.